# Selected Files can not display in FileChooser in JavaFX

Tags: filechooser

I have problem with my code where i want to know selected file in file chooser, i try with system.print.ln can respon selected file but with text take result null.
Where error happen?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want someone to look at your issue quickly, DONT put your code as screenshot. Anyway I think your issue is at declaring actionStatus field using @FXML. Remove the "static" keyword.

Comment: Hi Sai Dandem, 
Thank you for your advice, I will pay more attention to the details and thank you for the answers you gave to my questions